# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-item'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ngfor

I am trying to use ngFor to loop through items in my list. However, I get this warning on my browser and the list does not get displayed. How do I fix this? I have already added `BrowserModule` and `CommonModule` to my `@NgModule` imports in `app.module.ts`. This did not solve the issue.

> app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common"; //if we want to use ngFor and other types //then we need to include common module to be able to use it


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule 
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> workoutplan.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>workoutplan !!</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list> 
    <ion-item  *ngFor ="let workoutplan of workoutPlans">
      {{workoutplan.title}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only reason for this error could be using `*ngFor` inside the component that does not belong to `AppModule`. I am assuming that you are using `*ngFor` inside a component which is registered with some different Module(not AppModule or root Module).

Just import `CommonModule` in that particular module and add it to the `imports` array.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

imports: [CommonModule]
```

Comment: This is correct. The import needs to be in the module that declares `WorkoutPage`

Comment: I tried that before as well, does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you please add the module code where you have registered your workoutplan component.

Comment: Understanding the first paragraph led me in the right direction.